# Sequences and series of $\tan^n x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Please help me with this question:

> Investigate the convergence of the sequence 
>   $$\tan x, \quad \tan^2 x, \quad \tan^3 x, \quad \dots, \quad \tan^n x$$ for $x \in (-90^\circ, 90^\circ)$.
>
> Steps to follow: Find common ratio. Draw the graph. For which values $x$ for which the sequence will converge. Determine sum to infinity.

I did try to solve, but file type too big to upload my answers.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: The sequence converges iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \tan^n(x)=0$

Comment: Hint: for a fixed $x$, these are geometric sequences/series.